# SVN Info: Last Changed Date?

Tags: svn

I'm about to commit a big change to my production server, but I thought I ought to scribble down the revision # before I do so in case anything explodes, I can quickly revert back.

However, I just ran `svn info` on both the dev server, and the production server. The dev server says `Last Changed Date: 2010-11-23 16:32:10 -0800 (Tue, 23 Nov 2010)`, which doesn't seem right, because I just comitted a change a few seconds ago. What does that mean then? Is this giving me correct information? I want to make sure I have the right revision #.

Comment: `svn log | head` gives me the correct date/time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to run an `svn update` before the `svn info`. The reason `svn log` "works" is because that talks to the server, whereas `svn info` look at the local checkout.

Answer (score 2):

```
svnversion .
```

Also [seems to work](http://www.zorched.net/2006/07/20/getting-the-revision-number-of-your-subversion-working-copy/).